# Snowflake: What code do I need to copy all views from a schema on PRD to the same schema on TST?

Tags: sql, view, copy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm very new on this side so please be patient if I do not ask my question correctly :-)
In snowflake I want to copy all the views from a schema in PRD db into a schema in TST db.
The schema already does exist in TST.
I do not have the grants to directly make a copy from all the views from PRD into TST.
So I want to create an sql in PRD and use it in TST for the copy.

BR,
Jan

Comment: Hi - you can use get_ddl at the schema level to get the creation scripts for everything in a schema. You would need to edit the result to remove any objects you do not need

Comment: thanks, but I have more than 200 views. Is this possible in 1 big script? I'm not that familiar in sql.

Comment: When you run get_ddl for a schema it should list all the view creation statements together so just find where they start/end and delete everything before/after this section

Answer (score 0):

You can use information_schema.views object to collect definition. And then execute in Test.

First point to TEST instance and then execute below.

```
DECLARE 
    QUERY STRING;
BEGIN
    select view_definition into :QUERY from PRD.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS where view_definition like '%MY_VIEW%'  ;
    execute immediate(:QUERY) ; 
END;
```